# Batch file to replace whole line if particular word is present

Tags: batch-file, replace

I have a file like

```
//output:One line,file info always
-hF1
+ffn
-"format=%(%f %l%): Error -> %t %n %m"

//Do not break lines
-width(0,0)
```

What I want to do is reading a text from text file and replace the complete line in which the searched text is present by another line .

Example:
Output of above file should be like

```
    //output:One line,file info always
    -hF1
    +ffn
    //See below line is changed
    -"format=<message><file>%f</file> <line>%l</line> <type>%t</type> <code>%n</code> <desc>%m</desc></message>"<desc>%m</desc></message>"

    //Do not break lines
    -width(0,0)
```

Here I have searched for word `format' in text file and replaced that complete line.

Answer (score 0):

Using this batch file: repl.bat - http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3855
this command works here.  input.txt and output.txt are the files, and \x22 represents a quote.  BTW your replace command has unbalanced quotes.  The string being searched for is `format=` anywhere in the line.

```
type input.txt|repl "^.*format=.*" "-\x22format=<message><file>%f</file> <line>%l</line> <type>%t</type> <code>%n</code> <desc>%m</desc></message>\x22<desc>%m</desc></message>\x22" mx >output.txt
```